# Writing a bash script to reboot for given time and then start up

Tags: linux, bash, microcontroller, reboot

Hi I'm trying to right a bash script that would reboot my micro controller from a remote server for a given time (lets say 10 min). A better way to say it is, i wanna keep it off for 10 min and then reboot.

so far i've tried but it doesnt seem to work

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "Have you turned it off and on again?"

reboot 

shutdown -t 10 -r
shutdown -r now
/sbin/shutdown -t 10 -r
/sbin/shutdown -r now
/sbin/reboot -t 1000
```

Comment: You can't, from a running script, schedule a wake-up unless you've got hardware that can do that that you can interact with.

Comment: It does not make sense. If your computer is halted it cannot count until something and then do that. It is halted and it does nothing. What you need is an **external** device with a clock that you can program to stop / start your computer. Do you have one?

Comment: im accessing a microcontroller from a server. This thing heats up so i wanna shut it down a couple of times a day for 10 min.

Comment: Does it have wake-on-lan?

Comment: Nope, i don't believe it does. It's called the 'WRT node'

Comment: There is always http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Coffee.html , about switching ON/OFF a coffe machine via a relay/triac connected to a parallel port (with knowledge, it may be possible to adapt the technique to use some more readily available port, e.g. a serial port from a USB/serial adapter). Another option is using a Remote Power Switch, or a remotely controlled UPS.